# Tensorflow model does not load correctly - INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a saved model saved_model.pb which when I serve it through tensorflow/serving container, loads and executes as expected. However, if I try to load this model locally by calling the tensorflow method tf.saved_model.load (in jupyter notebook)

```
# Both methods produce the same message below
# model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)
```

I get the following message:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
```

I know that the variables should be present when the model is saved, mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/serving_basic) 
If this is the case, why does this model load correctly in a tensorflow/serving container?

I am running tensorflow 2 and confirm that the tensorflow/serving version is the same.

[image]

The object that is returned from the load model method is an autotrackable object and does not have a predict method. It is not callable.

```
tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable
```

Unfortunately, this work was done by someone else and the protobuf file is all I have. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you running jupyter notebook in a different `env` if so check the `versions`

Comment: @ksooklall yes, I am running a anaconda environment with the same version of tensorflow (2.0.0)

Comment: @noobie: Is it resolved now. Else, Can you try loading the model using `tf.keras.models.load_model` and check how it goes? Thanks

Comment: @TensorflowSupport - it has been some time, so we have placed this on hold. I have tried both statements below, but no luck: model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path) as well as model = tf.saved_model.load(model_path)